# MySQL STR_TO_DATE v/s DATE_FORMAT

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table called test, the structure code is given below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `assigned_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

And the table is containing following data :

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `name`, `assigned_date`) VALUES
(0, 'A', '2012-12-23'),
(0, 'B', '2012-12-25');
```

Now the problem is when I run the following query it doesn't return me any row.

```
SELECT name 
FROM test 
WHERE 
     DATE_FORMAT(assigned_date, '%m/%d/%Y') >= '12/01/2012'
     AND 
     DATE_FORMAT(assigned_date, '%m/%d/%Y') <= '01/02/2013'
```

But When I use the following commands it returns me two rows as expected.

```
SELECT name 
FROM test 
WHERE
     assigned_date >= STR_TO_DATE('12/01/2012', '%m/%d/%Y')
     AND 
     assigned_date  <= STR_TO_DATE('01/02/2013', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

What is the difference ? Why **DATE_FORMAT** didn't work ?

Please Help with this I have used date_format function through out a site. Now it seems like I have to update the entire site.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are unsure about a function, at least put some logic in your comparison. Year will always increase, month will reset every 13th, and days will be min 1 max 31. Why don't you arrange it as year|month|date therefore you can safely allow the query to automatically compare it as numbers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DATE_FORMAT` converts DATE to STRING. 
`STR_TO_DATE` converts STRING to DATE.

From MySQL Docs

- [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
- [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Answer (score 2):

DATE_FORMAT didn't work because it is converting assigned_date to a string in mm/dd/yyyy format and then comparing that string to your two string constants - and there *is* no string that is >= a string starting 12 and <= a string starting 01.

Comment: You can arrange the string using DATE_FORMAT(assigned_date,'%Y%m%d') in yyyymmdd therefore the latest date will be the biggest number (logically). For example in this case: DATE_FORMAT(assigned_date,'%Y%m%d') >= '20121201' and DATE_FORMAT(assigned_date,'%Y%m%d') <= '20130102'

Comment: @4LeaveCover DATE_FORMAT is useless here; they could just do `assigned_date >= '2012-12-01' and assigned_date <= '2013-01-02'`

Comment: Yes I agree with you. But you do notice he arranged the year|month|days in a bad practice right? That caused him the problem at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The DATE_FORMAT() function formats a date as specified by a format mask.

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, format_mask)
Example:
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2017-06-15", "%M %d %Y");
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(BirthDate, "%W %M %e %Y") FROM Employees;
```

MySQL STR_TO_DATE() returns a datetime value by taking a string and a specific format string as arguments.

```
STR_TO_DATE(str,format);
Example:
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('18,05,2009','%d,%m,%Y');
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('May 18, 2009','%M %d,%Y');
```